# Price slider extension is not working in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, extensions, exception-error

I have installed the free third party extension for price slider in Magento 2. After installing the extension, I ran upgrade, deploy, cache commands but I'm getting the below error:

```
Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.created_in' in 'where clause'
```

I have also tried running reindex command but still there is an error.

Could anyone please help me how to rectify this error?

[image]

Comment: Please briefly update your question

Comment: @Devidas, I have updated my question, please check

Comment: 'created_in' column is missing in your table. Please check Setup/InstallSchema.php and UpgradeSchema.php

Comment: There is no setup folder inside module directory

Comment: your extension is paid or free ?

Comment: Its a free extension

Comment: Manually you add created_in column in your table when its work then using UpgradeSchema.php to add column

Comment: send me extension link i will check

Comment: Here's the link: https://github.com/emizentech/magento2-price-slider

Comment: If I manually add the column, it will cause any issue

Comment: which table showing error? please show me full error log

Comment: Please check the question. I have added the screenshot of error log